# IOS Signing Errors for Building for IPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I made a game with Unity and used the IOS Export option on my windows machine, and then I copied over the Xcode project to test it on my device before I try and release it. I have a free developer account, but it keeps giving me the error:

**Failed to code sign 'Unity-iPhone'**
No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “9P75XXXXXX” were found.

Xcode can attempt to fix this issue. This will reset your code signing and provisioning settings to recommended values and resolve issues with signing identities and provisioning profiles.

There is then an option to "Fix Issue" but once I click that, I get the error '**Could not generate key pair for CSR**'

I have tried other fixed for the Could not generate key pair for CSR Error, but when I go into my Keychain Access and try to request a certificate from the certificate authority, I go all the way to the end, but then I get the error "**User Interaction is Not Aloud**".

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I was just fiddling around with this not twenty minutes ago. Apple's WWDR certificate expired last month. See if this helps your problem: https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/45siza/this_certificate_has_an_invalid_issuer/

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yeah, tried that, Still no joy